# Angular JS deep linking $routeProvider reload not working

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I have the following config for routes:

```
app.config( function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

// Routes
$routeProvider.when('/admin', {
    templateUrl : '/app/partials/dashboard.html',
    controller  : 'DashboardCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/admin/settings', {
    templateUrl : '/app/partials/settings.html',
    controller  : 'SettingsCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/404', {
    templateUrl : '/app/partials/404.html',
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Everything is working except, when I'm on `/admin/settings` and reload the page, it redirects to `404`. I tried removing the html5Mode, it works. However, I really want to use html5Mode. What am I missing? Please help me.

Oh, btw, I'm using AngularJS 1.1.5.

Comment: This is a known error in Angular 1.1.5, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2861.

Comment: Wow this bug just cost me an hour :(.  Good find @jclancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar error and solved it by inserting `<base href='my_app_base_url'></base>` into my `index.html` page, in the head. The idea came from this GitHub issue (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2774) and this other one (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2868), as well as the one I mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

try $location.path('/404').replace();